# How add a new account in App Services "MySql In App" on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, phpmyadmin

I want to import a data base on Azure and I need to connect this one to my website but i need the identifiant and password. Azure is using phpMyAdmin for configure the data base and at the begining i was connected with "azure" id.
So now i want to create a new account to connect me at my data base MySQL in app.

I'm already try to add a new line in the file : `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini` and delete this file : `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt` but it's doesn't works. Now i can't log with phpMyAdmin because the password is encrypted.

line at the begining: `Database=localdb;Data Source=127.0.0.1:49383;User Id=azure;Password=6#vWHD_$`
And i try to add this : `Database=localdb;Data Source=127.0.0.1:49383;User Id=Admin;Password=test`

How i can have the password encrypted? Or create a new account to connect me on to MySql with PhpMyAdmin ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the authentification, you need first to create a new user in phpMyAdmin after you just have to change the file `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini`with your new account then save it. After delete the file `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt`and restart the web app and you are connected with your new account.